# How to interact with a SKSpriteNode after another one of the same var name has been created?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I appologise for the confusing question title, but I wasn't quite sure how to phrase my question. My ultimate goal is to remove an SKSpriteNode a certain amount of time after it's creation. However, there is a small complication. Using the following code

```
func remove() {
  laser.removeFromParent()
}

runAction(
    SKAction.sequence([
       SKAction.waitForDuration(5.0),
       SKAction.runBlock(remove)
       ])
)
```

I'm able to remove the SKSpriteNode I named 'laser'. When I call my function once, fireLasers(), everything runs smoothly and the laser disappears after 5 seconds. The problem is when I call it twice within a period of 5 seconds. When this happens, the first laser will stick around indefinitely and the second disappears earlier than intended. I understand why this happens, but would like to know if there's a way around it. Here's the code for the GameScene which creates the world, background image, player Sprite, and defines the fireLasers function. There's a lot of stuff that goes on in the ViewController that works with the velocities and directions of the sprites, but I hope this is sufficient to find a solution.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var player = SKSpriteNode()
var world = SKShapeNode()
var worldTexture = SKSpriteNode()
var laser = SKShapeNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.size = CGSizeMake(view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height)

    // Add world
    world = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(7000, 7000))
    world.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromPath: world.path!)
    world.fillColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    self.addChild(world)

    // Add Background Image
    worldTexture = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grid")
    worldTexture.size = CGSize(width: 7000, height: 7000)

    world.addChild(worldTexture)

    // Add player
    player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    player.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity  = false
    player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    world.addChild(player)




    }

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    world.position.x = -player.position.x
    world.position.y = -player.position.y
}


func fireLasers() {
    laser = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(10, 50))
    laser.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 10, height: 50))
    laser.position.x = player.position.x
    laser.position.y = player.position.y + CGFloat(50)
    laser.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
    laser.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    laser.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity  = false
    world.addChild(laser)

    func remove() {
        laser.removeFromParent()
    }
    runAction(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.waitForDuration(5.0),
            SKAction.runBlock(remove)
            ])
    )


}



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of keeping a reference to the laser (which will, as you noticed, force you to only have one around at a time), why not run an action on the created laser nodes themselves? This will allow you to use the handy `SKAction` class method `removeFromParent()`:

```
let newLaser = makeNewLaser()
let laserAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(5), SKAction.removeFromParent()])
newLaser.runAction(laserAction)
```